# Delphi how to save #temptable data into another table with dataset/dataSetProvider/ADOQuery?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, dataset

My code is like:

```
with ArrangementClientDataSet do
begin
    close;
    dataset.commandText := 'exec getArrangementData';
    open;

    edit;
end;
```

In procedure the code is like

```
select cyear,ccode from #arrangement
```

So when I click query button the dbgrid shows the data.

And now I want to add a save button so that when I click, the data can be saved into another table 'arrangement'.

The code on Save button is:

```
procedure SaveToolButtonClick(Sender:TObject);
begin
    with ArrangementClientDataSet do
    begin
        first;
        ApplyUpdates(0);
    end;
end;
```

I tried to set

```
procedure DataSetProviderGetTableName(Sender:TObject;DataSet:TDataSet;var TableName :String);
begin
    TableName := 'arrangement';
end;

procedure ADOQueryAfterOpen(DataSet:TDataSet);
begin
    with ArrangementADOQuery do
    begin
        fieldByName('cyear').providerFlags := [pfInUpdate,pfInKey];
    end;
end;
```

But it doesn't work, SQL Server Profiler can't catch the insert SQL.

If I change a value in dbgrid and then click the save button SQL Server Profiler can catch a update SQL like

```
update arrangement set ccode='1' where pfInKeyField = '2022'
```

But it's not right because data is not yet contained in table

So what should I do?

Comment: 'ADOQuery.fieldByName.providerFlags := [pfInUpdate,pfInKey];' does not compile. That's just the first reason.

Comment: I just abbreviated it, the full writeup is:with arrangementADOQuery do begin fieldbyname('field').providerFlags :=[pfInUpdate,pfInKey]; end;The fact that the update triggered properly also shows this

Comment: There are too many questions here all at once. You are assuming that what you have already done is right, which causes you to come to the incorrect conclusion later. You need to a. provide full un-abbreviated code that pertains to 1 question, and 2. ask only that 1 question.